# Pie chart of frequency counts

Tags: r, plot, charts

I've imported a 1-column excel file using `gdata`, the data is as follows

```
3 4 3 3 1 4 1 3 2 3 1 1 4 2 3 3 2 6 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 6 1 3 2 2 1 2 2 4 2
```

I'm using the `pie(md[, 1])` command to create a pie chart for the data, however, I'm getting the following chart when I do this:

[image: Pie chart].

It's taking the data as 1-40 and then creating the pie width to the data sample rather than having 5 segments (1,2,3,4,6) with width created by the amount of times the result appears, i.e. the frequency counts of unique elements in the vector. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could try `pie(table(md[, 1]))`

Comment: Spot on, thanks mate, new to R and it's confusing for beginners!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `?table` function to compute frequencies before applying `pie`:

```
table(x)
#x
# 1  2  3  4  6 
#10 13 11  4  2
```

Then, to produce the pie chart of frequencies:

```
pie(table(x))
```

produces:

[image: pie]

```
x <- scan(text = "3 4 3 3 1 4 1 3 2 3 1 1 4 2 3 3 2 6 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 6 1 3 2 2 1 2 2 4 2")
```